# Selecting specific rows from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below table (in picture) which is kind of inventory table and shows how many items comes in and how many goes out from stock, and **item_id** is the foreign key from another table.

I want to select those records that has no **out** from the stock, in other word i want to select those records which are highlighted in green (in the picture).

Thanks.

**Sorry for poor English**

The Table

[image]

Comment: i have tried this but it seems stupid coz i know that it is not working and also i don't have any other idea.
SELECT * FROM `the_table` WHERE in <> 0 AND out = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from `table` where id in (select id from `table`group by id having sum(out)=0);
```

for deleting those values use:

```
delete t1
from `your_table` as t1 
join (select item_id from `your_table`group by item_id having sum(item_out)=0) t2 on t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

Comment: I think it worked for me, now i want to delete does records, please help coz the delete with ur query is not working for me

Comment: it gives this error - You can't specify target table 'the_table' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' where out=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table to itself: `SELECT t.* FROM <your_table> AS t LEFT JOIN <your_table> AS t1 ON t.item_id=t1.item_id WHERE t1.out>0 AND t1.item_id IS NULL`